# How do I use "memusage" commmand for check Memory usage of Particular program

Tags: ubuntu, memory, command

I Want to check Memory usage of the Particular program.

I'm trying to use the `memusage` command, as documented in [its manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/memusage.1.html) which is also present in Ubuntu. But running it produces

```
root@username:~# memusage filename
No command 'memusage' found, did you mean:
Command 'gmemusage' from package 'gmemusage' (universe)
memusage: command not found
```

I want to check the memory usage for a program by using the `memusage` command. What do I have to do?

If I try to install this command like this I get:

```
Root@Username#apt-get install memusage
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package memusage
```

Comment: Obviously the program is not installed.

Comment: if I try to install its showing like this In Question I edited @Buddika

Answer (score 4):

> What do I have to do?

1. Obtain [the Debian *source* package for GNU libc](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/glibc).
2. Ensure that it builds the `memusagestat` command.
3. Patch the files in [its `debian/debhelper.in` directory](https://salsa.debian.org/glibc-team/glibc/tree/sid/debian/debhelper.in) so that the [the `malloc/memusage.sh` script](https://sources.debian.org/src/glibc/2.27-5/malloc/memusage.sh/) and the `memusagestat` command are included in one of the existing built binary packages, or a new `memusage` package.  [They currently are not](https://packages.debian.org/search?mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=memusage).
4. Contact [the Debian Maintainers for this project](https://salsa.debian.org/groups/glibc-team/-/group_members) and get them to incorporate your patches into the official Debian source.
5. Get the Ubuntu people to build new binary packages.  [Debian is of course the origin of the Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/artful/glibc).
6. Install the new/modified binary package.

This procedure, in particular steps 3, 4, and 5, takes some time.

Comment: I take the OP is confused that `man memusage` is giving a description for a command that is not installed nor can be installed. The answer is that, indeed, there isn't any package for memusage.

Comment: Steps 4 and 5 can be circumvented by building the package locally (but both should be done in parallel). Part of the confusion stems from the fact that the manpages are shipped by the `manpages` package and not anything related to the GNU C library.

Comment: Also note that the Debian maintainers should be contacted using [the listed maintainer address](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/glibc), which is `debian-glibc@lists.debian.org`, not individually. The best approach is really to file a bug.

Comment: … and hope that it does not languish for 13 years like Debian Bug #334120 has.  (-:

Comment: I'm Using UBUNTU 17.10. so what should I do for that @JdeBP

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Bug#91815](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=91815), the binaries are no longer shipped with the `libc6` package.

So you would have to download the sources (`apt source libc6`) then get the required dependencies (`apt build-dep libc6`), and then compile.

Looks like the bug is being addressed as of July 8 2020 though.

Comment: ```$ apt source libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'glibc' as source package instead of 'libc6'
E: Unable to find a source package for glibc
```

Comment: @Bram you need the `deb-src` lines in your repository configuration.

Answer (score 0):

`memusage` is available in the `libc-devtools` package [since version 2.31-8](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1210957/accepted-glibc-231-8-source-amd64-into-experimental-experimental/). This is available in Ubuntu 21.04 and later, Debian 11 and later, and derivatives.